# C++: Templates of child classes only

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to make a template only work with child classes of a base class? Something like this:

```
template<BaseClass T>
class FooBar
{
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Either use a static assert from your favourite C++ library (such as [this boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html#boost_staticassert.function)), or put a call in the constructor (or other code which will always be generated when the code is used) to a do-nothing function taking a BaseClass type, for example:

```
template<class T>
class FooBar
{
public:
    FooBar () {
        Check(static_cast<T*>(0));
    }

private:
    void Check ( BaseClasse* ) {} 
};
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can test it in the constructor using Boost:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template<class T>
class FooBar{
  FooBar(){
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_base_of<BaseClass,T>::value);
  }
};
```

Or if you don't want a static assert, something like this is also nice sometimes:

```
typedef char ERROR_T_must_be_derived_from_BaseClass[boost::is_base_of<BaseClass,T>::value ? 1 : -1];
```

Since whoever compiles your code will be brought to this line and has a "readable" error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make it work with a static assert. See [Boost.StaticAssert](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Boost/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html)