# Can I specify that template arguments ought to be subclasses of some base class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that is designed to work with a certain type of parameter. Is there any way that I can enforce that the template parameter be a pointer to a subclass of some type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175219/restrict-c-template-parameter-to-subclass

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Templates of child classes only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612521/c-templates-of-child-classes-only)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct B { };
struct D : B { };

template <typename T>
struct S {
    typedef typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, T>::value>::type check;
};

int main()
{
    S<B> x;   // Ok!
    S<D> y;   // Ok!
    S<int> z; // Not ok!
}
```

The `enable_if` utility and the `is_base_of` type trait are part of the C++0x Standard Library, but both available in Boost as well.

Comment: Could also put that into the template parameters: `template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B, T>::value>::type>`.

Comment: Yes, you could, but then your template parameter list quickly gets unwieldy.

Comment: Personally I find `static B* check = (T*) 0` clear enough. No need to include Boost for just this.